# Trying to use set with a segue to set properties

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard

I am trying to set the bigImage, cadImage, and number in my class IDViewController. But these are never set when I use the code below. Obviously these properties are synthesized properly, and are on a scene on my storyboard. Am I missing something here?

ViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"leftMainSegue"])
    {
        IDViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];

        [vc.bigImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
        [vc.number setText:@"01"];

    }
}
```

IDViewController.h

```
@interface IDViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIImageView *bigImage;
    UIImageView *cadImage;
    UILabel *number;

}
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *bigImage;
@property (nonatomic) UIImageView *cadImage;
@property (nonatomic) UILabel *number;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though `IDViewController` is initialized by the time `prepareForSegue:` is called, it probably hasn't loaded its view and therefore not the sub-views that you're trying to update.

You would be better to set the image and text into properties directly owned by the controller and then set them into the views in `viewDidLoad:`.

Something like....  (Warning! Not checked by compiler!)

In IDViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *inputImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *inputString;
```

In IDViewController.m:

```
@synthesize inputImage = _inputImage;
@synthesize inputString = _inputString;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
    self.bigImage.image = self.inputImage;
    self.number.text = self.inputString;
...
}
```

In ViewController.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
...
    vc.inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];
    vc.inputString = @"01";
...
}
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! Could you provide an example of how I would do that I am still new to this.

Comment: I've updated the answer.  The new code was written in the browser, so there may be errors...but it should at least give the general idea.